# How to write data into a file based on the position in python

Tags: python

I am having some trouble in extracting data from a list of dicts based on the position defined in my configuration. 
Scenario:
I am getting a list of dict from the vertica table (thru some method call) and I need to write those data (key as header and value as the data content) in the file, so that I can upload that file to sftp for some other purpose.

Example

```
# data received in a list of dict
new_list = [{'Table':'A', 'Column':'C1', 'DataType':'int'},
            {'Table':'A', 'Column':'C2', 'DataType':'varchar'},
            {'Table': 'B', 'Column': 'C3', 'DataType': 'int'}
           ]
```

My configuration defined in such a way that "Table" data will start from 0 to 10, "Column" will start from 11 to 25 and then "DataType" will start from 25 to 35 in the file. Also if there is not enough data to fill the defined range then need to pad with space after the data till it reaches the specified field length. So I expect output like below. Here the list is dynamic in nature. I know I have to use `seek()`, but bit confused.

```
Table          Column                    DataType
A              C1                        int
A              C2                        varchar
B              C3                        int
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Relying on list indices to find your data is brittle and wasteful. I'd use another data format than lists; what about a dictionary of dictionaries? json? Anyway, I'm nore sure I understand the question exactly. Where's your file writing code?

Comment: My recommendation would be using `struct` module but would be a long answer

Comment: Open the file for writing and updating with `w+` mode.  Call `seek()` to move to the desired location, then use `write()` to write the desired data.

Comment: It will be difficult to use `seek` since the elements you're storing have different lengths, and therefore different files will have different `seek` locations.  That is, `seek` is based on bytes, not row or column information.

Comment: let me explain what i am trying to do: one of my method, queries the vertica table and gives me the output as a list of dicts as shown in example. So here i need to generate a file based on the position defined so that i can upload that file to sftp. is this clear to you? @jDo

Comment: @Pradeep The question is where you should be explaining what you are tying to do, not the comments.

Comment: Are you updating an existing file, or creating a new one?  `seek` is typically only used for updating an existing file.  If you're creating a new file you shouldn't need it.

Comment: always create a new file @John

Comment: Then you don't need `seek` at all.  If you want to write data at, say, column twenty in the file, then make sure that your previous `write` call was for nineteen bytes.

Comment: @Pradeep No, it's not entirely clear but it sounds like a slightly odd approach. If you have to add extra elements to the list to maintain the order, there's probably something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want, using [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
>>> def f(lst):
        print('{:<10s}{:<15s}{:<10s}'.format(*['Column','Table','DataType']))
        for row in new_list:
            s = '{d[Column]:<10s}{d[Table]:<15s}{d[DataType]:<10s}'.format(d=row)
            print(s)


>>> f(new_list)
Column    Table          DataType  
C1        A              int       
C2        A              varchar   
C3        B              int
```

Comment: Thanks. seems like the data is formatted correctly. need to do the same for the headers too. @Iron Fist

Comment: @Pradeep .. You could do that yourself as a practice, but nevertheless, code updated.

Comment: @Pradeep...If you feel this answer provided the right solution for you, then feel free to accept it or anyone else, otherwise, if your issue is still not solved, *do* edit your question with an update.

Comment: how can I make the above snippet dynamic means if I have another list of dict which has different key value pair and also the position could vary too. @Iron Fist

Answer (score 0):

I'm partly guessing but maybe this is what you want:

```
new_list = [{'Table':'A', 'Column':'C1', 'DataType':'int'},
            {'Table':'A', 'Column':'C2', 'DataType':'varchar'},
            {'Table': 'B', 'Column': 'C3', 'DataType': 'int'}
           ]
# print in terminal
print "\t".join(new_list[0].keys())
for d in new_list:
    print "{}\t{}\t{}".format(d["Table"], d["Column"],d["DataType"])

# write to file
with open("outfile", "w") as f:
    f.write("\t".join(new_list[0].keys()) + "\n")
    for d in new_list:
        f.write("{}\t{}\t{}\n".format(d["Table"], d["Column"],d["DataType"]))
```

Result:

```
$ cat outfile 
Column  Table   DataType
A       C1      int
A       C2      varchar
B       C3      int
```

Comment: but no where you mentioned the position where the data will start and end. I need to follow the positions for each header otherwise the some other process will read wrong data. @jDo

Comment: @Pradeep Well, then do `for d in new_list[0:9]:`, `for d in new_list[10:24]:`, etc. If the columns are always 10 indices apart, you can probably use modulus 9 or 10